# should i change the ABI when using a proxy pattern?

Tags: abi, proxy-contracts

i would like to ask you a question about the proxy pattern.
Suppose I published an ERC721 token contract(version 1) and also I'm using proxy contract(OpenZeppelin upgradable proxy).

if i add a new function this logic contract(version 2), do i need to change the ABI from web3 client? For using new function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ABI basically describes what functionality the contract supports. If you don't update the ABI, the client doesn't know of the new functionality.

So, yes, you should update the ABI.

Strictly speaking, you don't *have to* update the ABI, you can just call the new functionality in a dynamic way even without the ABI, but things are much easier if the new functionality is listed in the ABI.

Comment: I really confused about this. Thank you so much :)